# Extracting N frames per second using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf trim=10.021295:22.621295 -r 1  frames/frame_%d.png

This returns 24 frames instead of 12

Comment: Just use `-vf trim=10.021295:22.621295,fps=1/5`

Answer (score -1):

Trim filter does not modify the timestamps. If you wish for the output timestamps to start at zero, insert a setpts filter after the trim filter.

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf trim=10.021295:22.621295,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS frames/frame_%d.png

Comment: This does not enforce extraction to N frames per second,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).